# CPU time of same workload changes when using cgroups

Tags: linux, memory, time, cpu, cgroups

I am performing the exact same computation on the exact same dataset in two ways:

- Just executing the code as per usual via the command line.
- Limiting memory usage using cgroups v2 in Linux.

And I'm getting unexpected results when using the `time` command.

1. Without limiting memory:

```
real 15.08s
user 14.61s
sys 0.42s
cpu 99%
```

2. Whem limiting memory using cgroups:

```
real 58.11s
user 1.85s
sys 31.37s
cpu 57%
```

I was expecting the **user time** to stay the same, but it decreases considerably under cgroups despite the fact that it's the same task on the same amount of data.

Comment: Does your workload perhaps spend some time busy-waiting for I/O or something else?  Or stop itself after some amount of wall-clock time rather than a fixed amount of work, so it would spend less CPU time if it was sleeping (I/O wait for paging) some of the time?  I don't see any obvious mechanism for actually getting the same work done with less CPU time under intense memory pressure with heavy swapping.  Perhaps use `perf stat --all-user` to see if the user-space instruction count is the same.

Comment: Yes, when I limit the memory the process is spending more time waiting for I/Os. But the actual operations the CPU has to execute are still the exact same(it does not stop untill all the data is read). That's why I'm having a hard time understanding why it deceases so much. I thought I should have the same user time, with an increase in the sys time.

Comment: I was asking if (when running normally, not in a cgroup), whether some of the "user" time is **busy**-waiting, like running in a loop like `while(!io_ready()) {}` just burning CPU cycles waiting for something. Or another wild guess.  Unlikely, but as you say, normally you wouldn't expect `user` time to get a lot lower.  But you say the computation work is fixed, not dependent on wall-clock time, so that wouldn't explain the much lower user time, assuming you aren't doing anything crazy with non-blocking I/O.  `perf stat --all-user` should be able to confirm you run the same # of instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The results show **116,445,930,522  instructions** for the execusion without cgroups and **116,467,992,903 instructions** under cgroups. There's a diffrence but I'm not quite sure if it's significant to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, probably not significant.  Did user-space `cycles` (from perf stat --all user) and/or `task-clock` also confirm what the shell `time` command was telling you about using much less user time?

Comment: They basically have the same value for `cycles`, and the `task-clock`/`CPUs utilized` is consistent with the **real time**. I'm noticing there's a diffrences in the value for branches/sec (same number of brances but **281M/s without cgroups** and **181M/s with cgroups**), so I'm trying to figure out what that means.

Comment: When you say task-clock is consistent with `real` time, you mean it's similar to `real` not `user` time?  Maybe the task-clock software event counts a significant amount of time when you weren't actually running user-space instructions.  branches/sec is just calculated as `branches / task-clock`, so a higher than expected value for task-clock will affect all other counters.  `task-clock` might include `user` + `sys` time, so including all the time spent in the kernel while your process is `current`, running interrupt handlers and paging code.